# Understanding connection string atrributes

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string

I'm new to C# and all of .net. I'm trying to test my Nhibernate configuration using a test console app.

here's my test console app

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            NHibernateBase NHB = new NHibernateBase();
            NHB.Initialize("NHibernate.GuitarStore");
            System.Console.WriteLine("NHibernate.GuitarStore assembly initialized.");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string Message = ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Message += " - InnerExcepetion: " + ex.InnerException.Message;
             }
        System.Console.WriteLine();
        System.Console.WriteLine("***** ERROR *****");
        System.Console.WriteLine(Message);
        System.Console.WriteLine();
        System.Console.ReadLine();
        }

        }
    }
```

When I run the above program i get the error:

```
***** ERROR *****
Login failed for user 'BUGZILLA\Silon'.
```

Here's my connection string in my app.config

```
connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myGuitarStore;Integrated Security=True
```

I'm thinking it has to do with the Integrated Security part of the connection strings.

The problem is  that i dont understand the attributes(and their meaning) in the connection strings and i cant seem to find any article that expalins them easy enough.

----just in case you need it to understand the problem, here's the NHibernateBase class

```
 public class NHibernateBase
{
    private static Configuration Configuration { get; set; }
    protected static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }
    private static ISession session = null;
    private static IStatelessSession statelessSession = null;

    public static Configuration ConfigureNHibernate(string assembly)
    {
        Configuration = new Configuration();
        Configuration.AddAssembly(assembly);
        return Configuration;
    }

    public void Initialize(string assembly)
    {
        Configuration = ConfigureNHibernate(assembly);
        SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession Session
    {
        get
        {
            if (session == null)
            {
                session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            }
            return session;
        }
    }

    public static IStatelessSession StatelessSession
    {
        get
        {
            if (statelessSession == null)
            {
                statelessSession = SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession();
            }
            return statelessSession;
        }
    }

    public IList<T> ExecuteICriteria<T>()
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                IList<T> result = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>();
                transaction.Commit();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Integrated Security=True` simply means you are authenticating using Windows authentication, instead of passing your user id and password and authenticate through sql server itself.  If you are not doing windows authentication, then you can simply pass the user id and password as part of the connection string, see [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for other connection string formatst hat work.

You can also see this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article which describes each of the connection string properties

Comment: Thanks a lot. i changed the Integrated Security to false and added the user id and password...its all good now. thanks for the links too.  i also found this link which was easier for me to understand http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752.aspx#sse

Answer (score 1):

The way that you're connecting to the db (ie Windows auth vs SQL Server auth) is generally specified in the connection string. Right now you're trying to connect with Windows creds of the user who's running your application (and no password). I think you're better off reading about the security options SQL Server has to offer then reading about connection strings. You need to know how your db is set up in order to create a working connection string for it.

Here's a link to MSDN with some info about SQL Server security settings; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, consider how you connect with MSSMS; What credentials do you provide? What domain are you on? Do you use Windows Auth? If you can figure out how you connect there you can easily create a connection string that connects the same way - just find an example and edit it with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string, since a `username` and `password` is not included, is passing your current logged-in user's credentials when trying to connect to the database.  Ensure `Bugzilla\silon` has access to the tables you are attempting to query with nHibernate.

Otherwise, you can provide a SQL Server login account in the connection string (different from an AD login) using the `username=` and `password=` keys.